# Ramda return response as request body

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I'm new to Ramda, and I wonder how to do a simple task:

I have an action and I just want to return the request body

```
router.post('/', ctx => {
    ctx.body = ctx.request.body
})
```

I tried with lens, but with no success

```
const bodyLens = R.lensPath(['ctx', 'body'])
const reqLens = R.lensPath(['ctx','request', 'body'])

const set = R.pipe(R.view(reqLens), R.set(bodyLens))
router.post('/', ctx => {
    set(ctx)(ctx)
    ctx.body = ctx.request.body
})
```

How to make it work in an elegant way?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you want to achieve?

```js
const ctx = {
  request: {
    body: 'hello'
  }
}

const bodyLens = R.lensPath(['body'])
const reqLens = R.lensPath(['request', 'body'])

const _set = R.pipe(R.view(reqLens), R.set(bodyLens))

console.log(_set(ctx)(ctx))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.24.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

**Update**  If you want to achieve `ctx => _set(ctx)(ctx)` in a pointfree style, how about simplify your functions and import [`converge`](http://ramdajs.com/0.23.0/docs/#converge)?

```js
const ctx = {
  request: {
    body: 'hi'
  }
}

const _set2 = R.converge(R.assoc('body'), [R.path(['request', 'body']), R.identity])

console.log(_set2(ctx));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.24.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Almost, I wanted to create a function without wrapping in anonymous function. What I want to achieve is **router.post('/', _set)** where **_set** is a function that receives the obj **ctx**

Comment: Isn't that `const _set = (ctx) => R.pipe(R.view(reqLens), R.set(bodyLens))(ctx)(ctx)`?

Comment: @FranciscoBerrocal I updated my answer, wish it would help.

Comment: @choasia If `request` is a real request object with tons of props in it `merge` would merge all those additional props as well.

Comment: @YuryTarabanko you're totally right! I just updated my answer. Would you have a look to see if it is fine now?

Comment: @choasia Looks great now :)

Answer (score 1):

Lenses are actually ok if you want to read/write props in immutable manner. 
To make your function pointfree and avoid passing `ctx` multiple times you could use [`R.chain`](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#chain) instead of `pipe`

```js
const ctx = {
  request: {
    body: 'test'
  }
}

const setBody = R.chain(
  R.set(R.lensPath(['body'])),
  R.view(R.lensPath(['request', 'body']))
)

console.log(ctx, setBody(ctx))
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.24.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```